# React: How to create interface's attributes dynamically during runtime

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

at the moment I read documents from a collection according to a particular data model created by an interface in react.
This means the document's data is strongly saved in the attributes like:

dealContent.dealWelcome.productId where dealWeclome is a document-ID and an interface in react

Now we create documents dynamically in Firestore like:

dealcontent.MMDEde_dealWelcome.productId where MMDEde_dealWelcome is the doument-ID

Is there a way to create an attribute like MMDEde_dealWelcome during runtime, so the correct path in Firestore is read?

Best regards,
Johannes